# accessing UIView subclass in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Let's say I have `SomeViewController: UIViewController`, and I have a custom view `CustomView: UIView`, defined as a XIB, that I want to display. This custom view will be reused in other view controllers and even multiple times in the same view controller.

```
class CustomView: UIView {
  @IBOutlet public var label: UILabel!
}
```

The way I have always added this view has been:

```
class UIExamples: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet private var myView: UIView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Assume makeViewFromNib returns the view [0] in the Nib. 
    let customView = makeViewFromNib(nib: "\(CustomView.self)", owner: self) as! CustomView
    customView.frame = myView.bounds
    myView.addSubview(customView)
  }
}
```

Let's say that later on I want to modify something about the `CustomView` via a public property `label`.

I could do it inside `viewDidLoad` ONLY BECAUSE I have access to `customView`, but what if I want to change it in some other function? What I have seen is that one would have to do

```
let customView = myView.subviews[0] as! CustomView
customView.label.text = "some text"
```

which does not look right.

So, I thought the right way should be this:

```
class UIExamples: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet public var customView: CustomView! // Now this is always a CustomView type

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Assume makeViewFromNib returns the view [0] in the Nib. 
    customView = makeViewFromNib(nib: "\(CustomView.self)", owner: self) as! CustomView
    customView.label.text = "some text" // DOES NOT WORK!
  }
}
```

That last line customView.label.text does not work. In fact, the label is not even seen on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to call explicitly `makeViewFromNib(nib: "\(CustomView.self)", owner: self)` 'cause you already have a loaded `customView` from Storyboard if you're using  `IBOutlet` in such case. And next point you should clarify -- which one does you use Storyboard or Xib.

Comment: Do you want to reuse the view in different view controllers or is it specifically for that one?

Comment: added clarification in first sentence.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://medium.com/@letatas/how-to-reuse-complex-xib-designed-views-in-storyboards-using-modern-swift-generics-property-e0b7c06b07a6 you may find the answer to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my own answer.

1. Create the XIB file.
2. Create the UIView subclass Swift file.
3. Under the XIB file owner's Identify Inspector custom class field, type in the UIView subclass name (your custom view).
4. Under the XIB file owner's Connections Inspector, make sure all IBOutlets in the Swift file are connected.
5. Add a view to the view controller and under its Identify Inspector custom class type, specify the custom class name.

Important: 
* In your XIB swift file, you have to properly load the XIB content view.

```
...

  /// Initializer used by Interface Builder.
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    configure()
  }

  /// Initializer used programmatically.
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
  }

...

func configure() {
  let contentView = // here use many of the functions available on the internet to 
                    // load a view from a nib. 
  // Then add this view to the view hierarchy. 
    addSubview(contentView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, didn't read (or maybe was reading before edit) that you use xib. If ViewController is created from xib with label in it this will be correct way:

set myView class in xib here:

[image: xib view screenshot]

and then connect IBOutlet (remove current one from xib here:

[image: outlets screenshot]

and then from code).

Now `myView.label.text = "some text"` should work without further issues.
Good luck!

---

If you create your view from code do it in this manner:

```
class UIExamples: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet private var myView: CustomView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Assume makeViewFromNib returns the view [0] in the Nib. 
    myView = makeViewFromNib(nib: "\(CustomView.self)", owner: self) as! CustomView
    myView.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(myView)
  }
}
```

Because you already have property storing this view in your view controller it's unnecessary to dig inside subviews, it will work like that

```
myView.label.text = "some text"
```

---

And reason for

```
customView = makeViewFromNib(nib: "\(CustomView.self)", owner: self) as! CustomView
    customView.label.text = "some text"
```

isn't working is because it's completely new view that wasn't added to your view controller subviews (also frame wasn't set BTW). And because you changed value of your customView property it's now not pointing to old instance of view, that is present in subviews (you can still see that "old one" but not change it).

But I really recommend to use pointer created once, as correct class to avoid casting. (Or creating view directly in xib / storyboard, otherwise `@IBOutlet` is not necessary)

Comment: I noticed myView.subviews is of type `[UIView]`. That's why I though you could not do  `customView.label.text`.

Comment: @anr yes, but all custom views (UIView subclasses) are of type UIView. It won't even need casting to UIView to add CustomView as a subview. It's "upcasting" - casting to superclass. And only downcasting (casting to subclass) needs to be explicit in this context. So you can (and should) use properties in convenient way, as suggested in my answer (`@IBOutlet private var myView: CustomView!`)

Comment: reading the answer one more time, I think there is something wrong: I want to be able to do `myView.label.text` (you are using customView.label.text). In fact, I tried `myView.label.text` and it does not work. Remember that I want to be able to do `myView.label.text` outside `viewDidLoad` and that means I only have access to `myView` and not `customView`.

Comment: @anr changed my answer a bit. It's really not necessary to add CustomView to another CustomView. If myView is created from storyboard / xib with class set to "CustomView" there just set myView to this class in code and use label directly (`myView.label.text = "some text"`), without creating view from nib at all

Comment: @anr Edited my answer for ViewController created from xib (for storyboard it's really similar)

Comment: apologies but I'm not clear with the new answer. Specific questions for the case where one wants to instantiate the view from a xib and later modify an outlet defined in said xib : 
1) should the file owner's class be the custom type or the default one, that is, NSObject. 
2) the custom view's class in the class inspector, I assume it must be the custom type, which is a subclass of UIView. It's the only thing that makes sense here. 
3) I think I'm missing the proper way to initialize a xib when one wants to use the way I am describing it. Thank you!